# flag change in python while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I want to send a request to an api in python using requests library. when I want to call the api first time, I should send a paramter but after the successful first call the parameter should not send. How can I handle this situation??
Example code:

```
        while True:
            firstTime = True -> This is the first time parameter
            params = {
                "accountNo": self.DEPOSIT,
                "lastTranKey": None if firstTime is True else "",
                "fromDate": fromDate,
                "toDate": toDate,
                "pageSize": length,
            }
            response = requests.post(
                url="",
                json=params,
                timeout=50
            )
            if response.status_code == 200:
                firstTime = False
```

Comment: put `firstTime = True` outside, before the loop

Answer (score 0):

You may put `firstTime` before the loop, to do it once

```
firstTime = True
while True:
    params = {
        "accountNo": self.DEPOSIT,
        "lastTranKey": None if firstTime else "",
        "fromDate": fromDate,
        "toDate": toDate,
        "pageSize": length,
    }
    response = requests.post(
        url="",
        json=params,
        timeout=50
    )
    if response.status_code == 200:
        firstTime = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the loop, set the first-time flag to true.  Then at the bottom of the loop, set it to false.

```
firstTime = True
while True:
    # do stuff
    firstTime = False
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. Note: This post was flagged as a low-quality post. – [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/31995829)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if else statement`.

```
first_time = True
while True:
    if first_time:
        #do the stuff only ones
        if response.status_code == 200:
            firstTime = False
    else:
        #do stuff for rest of the time
```